# How can I read Thorlabs Strain Gauge reader KSG101 in Python 3

Tags: python, dll, usb

Thorlabs provides no dedicated Python example on how to interface the KSG101 Strain Gauge reader. With the help of the Thorlabs support team I found a working solution which I want to share here.
System: Windows 10 64 bit
Thorlabs Kineses 32bit for 64 bit installed
Python 3.7.4 **32bit**

```
import os
import time
from ctypes import *


"""installation folder of Thorlabs"""
os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Thorlabs\Kinesis")

"""load dll for the Strain Gauge"""
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("Thorlabs.MotionControl.KCube.StrainGauge.dll")

"""Build device list"""
lib.TLI_BuildDeviceList()

"""get serial number of device, can be found in the Kineses interface"""
serialNumber = c_char_p(b"59000696")

"""open serial connection"""
lib.SG_Open(serialNumber)
time.sleep(1)

"""start measuring"""
lib.SG_StartPolling(serialNumber, 200)
time.sleep(1)

"""set to zero"""
lib.SG_SetZero(serialNumber)
time.sleep(5)


"""get current voltage from device"""
voltage = lib.SG_GetReadingExt(serialNumber, False, False)
print(voltage)
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works as is, you only have to adapt the serial number of your device and adapt the dll file path.